# Xamarin.Forms FreshMVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I'm using FreshMVVM to make a tabbed in Xamarin Forms app ,I'm also using FlowListView plugin, I added two empty pages with their pagesModel but when I'm testing the app I faced this unhandled exception , any help ? 
[this is a screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcy3d.png)

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FlowListView.Init();
        FreshIOC.Container.Register<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>();
     SetupPage();


    }

    void SetupPage()
    {

        var freshTab = new FreshTabbedNavigationContainer();
        freshTab.AddTab<NewProductsPageModel>("New", "document.png", null);//Unhandled exception here! 
        freshTab.AddTab<AllProductsPageModel>("All", "document.png", null);
        MainPage = freshTab;    
    }
```

Comment: Looks like this is not the right exception. It has a timeout retrieving the exception details which is a message from the IDE. Run it again to see if the message changes to get the real error message.

Comment: I ran it many times and closed the project and opened it and ran again ... it gives me the same error every time

Comment: Try putting a try/catch block around it and see if you can catch it that way, or check the application output window.